# Logging in to Database through JMS java

Tags: java, logging, asynchronous, log4j, activemq-classic

I am trying to develop a logging application. I am getting request in a SOAP web service. Now I want ot store the request POJO in the database as XML. So, When I am getting the request POJO; I need to put it into JMS queue.

There will be a listener on other end that will listen the queue and if any message is there; it will pick it and put it in to database.

I am using ActiveMQ and log4j for this purpose.

How to achieve it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you want to store the XML i beleive you want to log the full SOAP request & response. So, you can do it by creating the logging handlers as explained in below url:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html

Comment: Basically I would like to store the log in to a database through the using of JMS and a message listener in using Spring.

Comment: I hope the following serve your purpose: [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-logging-using)
It wasn't mentioned your are using spring, If I was in your place my choice would be spring integration and do the logging by using the wire tap:
[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-wiretap)

Comment: I am already following  your first link. Because I am new in Spring; I am not be able to grasp in Spring configuration. Thanks for your advice and answers.

Comment: You are welcome, it all depends on our requirement. Sometimes even we know all, but we don't implement because it can be hard for others to maintain.